# hi i have this value from click and i want to increase the value with 10%

Tags: javascript, html

i have this code
and want to make an incremental

```
 $('#orderBookPrice button[value="lowerBuy"]').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#lowerPriceLimit").val($('#bids table tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type').text());
    });
```

I tried:

```
 $('#orderBookPrice button[value="lowerBuy"]').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#lowerPriceLimit").val($('#bids table tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type').text() * 10% );
    });
```

when i click the button i get a value from api and i want to increase with 10% ..
ex: value 100 * 10% =110

Comment: Why not just use `value * 1.1`?

Comment: where to add this?

Comment: @TorNetwork `$("#lowerPriceLimit").val($('#bids table tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type').text() * 1.1);`

Comment: on html is not same?  <button class="btn-info" style="background:#08B006" value="lowerBuy" * 1.1 >Lower BUY 10%</button>

Answer (score 0):

Change 10% to 110% or 1.1 as par to LaLaLuka's comment.